# What is the fastest way to read a csv file sort the data then write the sorted data into another csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I have a massive data set ~600Gb of several csv files. Each csv file contains 1.3mil x 17 sets of data. It looks like this

```
index        duration  is_buy_order       issued        location_id  min_volume  order_id        price   range  system_id  type_id  volume_remain  volume_total  region_id    http_last_modified  station_id  constellation_id universe_id
0              90          True  2021-05-04T23:31:50Z     60014437           1  5980151223         5.05  region   30000001       18         249003        250000   10000001  2021-06-19T16:45:32Z  60014437.0          20000001         eve
1              90          True  2021-04-29T07:40:27Z     60012145           1  5884280397         5.01  region   30000082       18          13120        100000   10000001  2021-06-19T16:45:32Z  60012145.0          20000012         eve
2              90         False  2021-04-28T11:46:09Z     60013867           1  5986716666     12500.00  region   30000019       19            728           728   10000001  2021-06-19T16:45:32Z  60013867.0          20000003         eve
3              90         False  2021-05-22T14:13:15Z     60013867           1  6005466300      6000.00  region   30000019       19           5560          9191   10000001  2021-06-19T16:45:32Z  60013867.0          20000003         eve
4              90         False  2021-05-27T08:14:29Z     60013867           1  6008912593      5999.00  region   30000019       19              1             1   10000001  2021-06-19T16:45:32Z
```

I currently have it in a dataframe. I run it through some logic filter out all the data by a particular "region_id" im looking for then put that into an empty dataframe. Something like this:

```
path = pathlib.Path('somePath')
data = pd.read_csv(path)
region_index = data.columns.get_loc('region_id')

newData = pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)

for row in data.values:
  if row[region_index] == region.THE_FORGE.value:
    
    newData.loc[len(newData)] = row.tolist()
  
newData.to_csv(newCSVName, index=False)
```

This however takes ~74min to go through a single file... I need to do this over 600gb worth of files...

So as the title mentions what is the fastest way I can/ should do this that i can do iteratively over all the csv's.
I have thought about using async but not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: CSV format is just a bunch of lines of text(rows) separated by commas(columns) I cannot figure out what your python script is doing in terms of logic I could rather write you a full solution if you explain it more clearly but the performative way of executing such a task is to open the csv file and read it line by line then write to output file if criteria matches

Comment: Also if you really care about the performance you should use a language such as C/C++ or Rust

Comment: I'd be happy to help you out about the program you can message me in discord if you like @farzad1138

Comment: unfortunately it must be done in python not c++. But the logic there is loading the csv into a pandas dataframe then going through a for loop row by row and sorting it based in region_id. Then putting that data into an empty data frame. Once done i write that new data frame to a new csv.

Comment: code snippet you provided here looks like filtering data not sorting also variable region is not in the code it's just confusing to me

Comment: can you send the complete script so I can analyze it better

Comment: you are right it is filtering not sorting. I meant it as "sorting it out". Ah ya the column region id is cut off thats all. 17 columns is to much to print out to the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255356/discussion-between-x-farza-d-x-and-steven).

Comment: You don't really need the huge pandas module for this.  It would be quicker just to use the `csv` module and handle the filtering yourself.  You don't even need to store all the rows -- just filter on the fly.

Comment: It seems like you want to read a csv, filter out everything but a single region_id and then write it again. Correct? You don't need to go to a different language as suggested by @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X, just make sure you use the built-in vectorized operations already in pandas. If you do that, the heavy lifting is done in C under the covers.

Comment: @tdelaney yes you are correct, however it seems what im doing above is taking way to long ~74min. Is there something in pandas that i should use instead?

Comment: Yes, I'll have what I think is the answer in a minute.

Comment: You are using the pandas dataframe exactly how it t isn't meant to be used, you are iterating over it with a for loop, then you ate incrementally creating another dataframe row by row, which is going to be terribly slow

Comment: As others have mentioned, if you had just used the built-in csv.module to do this it would be **algorithmically significantly faster and require small,.constant space**. If you want to use pandas, you should use vectorized operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` offers optimized C based functions that work on the entire table using native data types. When you iterate rows, look at individual values and convert things to lists, `pandas` must convert its native data types to python objects - and that can be slow. As you assign new rows, pandas must copy the table you've built so far, and that gets more and more expensive as the table grows.

It looks like you could filter the dataframe by a single known region_id and write the csv directly

```
path = pathlib.Path('somePath')
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data[data['region_id'] == region.THE_FORGE.value]].to_csv(newCSVName, index=False)
```

Comment: let me run this and get back to you on the speed difference.

Comment: went from 74min to 20sec ty for your help

Comment: That's great! Sometimes python is only the condutor and packages like pandas are the orchestra.

Comment: ya i havent used a ton of pandas before so i knew it was what i needed to use however i knew what i was doing was wrong. I didnt know pandas worked like "data['region_id'] == region.THE_FORGE.value"

Comment: That's the goal of pandas - to broadcast operations across entire data sets. `data['region_id'] == region.THE_FORGE.value` creates a Series of `True/False` values for the entire column. Put it in `data[ ... ]` and you get a new dataframe of just the rows that were `True`. That's how it broadcasts the operations.

Comment: ya thats great! Almost like hashing it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So, I would probably just stick to the csv module for this. But if you want to use pandas, you need to used the vectorized operations it was designed to use, otherwise, you are being very inefficient, particularly, the way you create `newData` is quadratic time. But you just need to use a simple filtering operation, all you need is:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data[data['region_id'] == region.THE_FORGE.value].to_csv(newCSVName, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

20 seconds is pretty decent

this is my solution might be a bit faster since you want to processes 600GB of data

```
def csv_filter_function(input_path, output_path, filter_value):
    filter_value = int(filter_value)
    target_index = 0
    with open(input_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
        line = input_file.readline()
        target_index = line.split(",").index('region_id')
        with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
            output_file.write(line)
            while line:= input_file.readline():
                if int(line.split(",")[target_index]) == filter_value:
                    output_file.write(line)


csv_filter_function('file.csv', 'out.csv', region.THE_FORGE.value)
```

Comment: You really should use a for loop to iterate over the file, `for line in input_file:...`

Comment: I actually didn't know that thanks

Comment: I convert on the if statement there is no bug actually I tested it before posting an answer

Comment: Whoops, didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

@juanpa.arrivillaga suggested the `csv` module, which is another good option. Its looping in Python is slower but it doesn't read the entire file into memory, which is its own advantage. Here is a second solution that reads and writes line by line

```
import csv

path = pathlib.Path('somePath')
region_id = str(region.THE_FORGE.value)

with open(path, newline="") as infile, open(newCSVName, "w", newline="") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    header = next(reader)
    index = header.index('region_id')
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(row for row in reader
        if row[index] == region_id)
```